# Why Betweenness Centrality in large networks have negative values?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, network-analyst

I use GRASS `GIS v.net.centrality` to calculate betweenness centrality.
As far as I know there should be values from 0 to (n-1)(n-2) in any given network with n nodes.
However I got lots of negatives (see fig 1). Does anybody knows why? The 0 values are the ones at the end of network because there is not any short path for any pair of nodes that cross end points. It doesn't happen in smaller networks, this one has 157046 nodes.
Things I discovered about the `GIS v.net.centrality`:

- It  considers any network as a direct graph. That is shortest distance btw AB is not necessary the same as BA. That's all I know.
- If more than one network is about to be calculated, the scores are independent for any network.
- The valuers are not standardized.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I just read the notes of Daniel Bundala, the creator of the v.net component. The notes said that he used the Brandes Algorithm for Betweenness Centrality. Which is a fast method for that calculation. Here is the link https://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass/trunk/lib/vector/neta/centrality.c